# Converting TimeZone Date Object without Changing Time

Tags: node.js, angular, momentjs

I want to convert the date from one timeZone into another TimeZone

For Eg: "Sun May 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" is the current date object , i want to convert the date based on timeZone Offset. consider the offset is '+4.0', Then i want the desired output such as "Sun May 01 2019 00:00:00 +04:00", i have used moment utcOffset
but it gives result such as "Sun May 19 2019 22:30:00 GMT+0530".

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript). The top answer provides a good way how to do it in vanilla javascript.

If you would like to use a library to achieve that, I would suggest to look into [date-fns](https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns). It doesn't have the mutability issues that moment does. If you opt for using it, you should use it together with [date-fns-timezone](https://github.com/prantlf/date-fns-timezone)

Answer (score 0):

Try https://momentjs.com/docs/

If you want more control and internalization. But the Date object will be relative to browser that instantiates it. To represent time use the unix epoch, `(new Date).getTime() / 1000;`.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time